# How to create A script record using a SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suite

`nlapiCreateRecord` cannot create a script record, it can only load a created script record.
If I want to create a script record for example a suitelet.

```
nlapiCreateRecord('suitelet');// this is not a valid statement as suitelet is not a  valid internal id.
```

How can I create a script record using suite-script?
[image: This is the Picture.]

Answer (score 0):

> nlapiCreateRecord cannot create a script record, it can only load a created script record

First thing yes you can not create a script record using `nlapiCreateRecord` because for creating  a record in NetSuite valid `internalid` of the record type is mandatory. Again, using this method you can't also load  a created script record.

Note : For creating / loading an existing record you require to pass the internal id of the record type. But Netsuite doesnt expose any internal id for script records.